# How can I update Reyclerview after async-call with ViewModel

Tags: android, mvvm, retrofit, viewmodel, android-architecture-components

I use Android Architecture Components(LiveData + ViewModel, MVVM). I have a list of items as news feed, which I represent over recyclerview. The user can like an item on this feed, and then after retrofit success, this certain item should be then updated (count of likes & viewclicks are observable-fields).

What would be best practice to do this? My Recyclerview has a seperate ViewModel then the corresponding Fragment (because of Dagger-Injections in Fragment-ViewModel). I have a listener in my fragment, when User does a click on ratingBar. Should I send the Object + the observable Fields from recycler-adapter through the listener to fragment, and observe a liveData-Variable for changes to update Recyclerview-Adapter or is there another approach for it?

My approach at the moment:

Recyclerview:

```
getBinding().ratebarUservote.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float v, boolean fromUser) {
                if(fromUser) {
                    mListener.onRatingBarChange(tutorialsResponse, items.get(position).getId(), v, viewModel.clicksObservable, viewModel.likesObservable);
                }
            }
        });
```

Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onRatingBarChange(News tutorial, String tutId, float value, bservableField<Integer> clicksObservable, ObservableField<Integer> likesObservable) {
    viewModel.likeTutorial(tutorial, tutId, value, clicksObservable, likesObservable);
    viewModel.getTutorialChangedLiveData().observe(this, tutChanged ->  mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged());
}
```

Comment: One suggestion at least would be to move `observe` call out of `onRatingBarChange` (put it in your fragment's `onViewCreated()` method instead for example)